# k6. How to use the imported SharedArray object? Is it possible to do so?

Tags: javascript, performance, k6

I want to import an already initialized SharedArray object from another file. I'm getting an error saying "SharedArray is not defined".

The code is very simplified, but I tried to maintain the logic. Here, an answer to the question in the description is needed.

```
import { constant_with_shared_array } from 'path/to/file.js';

const data = constant_with_shared_array;

export const options = {some options}

export default function() {
    const response = hhtp.request('POST',${url}/api/some,JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the other file?

I expect you have forgotten to import SharedArray `import { SharedArray } from "k6/data"`

Comment: @МихаилСтойков In another js file, only export constants and functions are stored. No imports are included in the file. The import of SharedArray is included in the file with the Default function.
Does this mean that the SharedArray is initialized before the import? And do we need to add the SharedArray import to the file that contains the constant with the SharedArray object?

Comment: @МихаилСтойков 
Here is the code from another file where the imported constant is located: 
`export const data_load_array = new SharedArray('test_data_load', function() {
  const data_load_json = JSON.parse(open('../../data/collector/test_data_lt_3kb.json'));
  return data_load_json;
});`

Comment: The error means the JS engine has no idea what `SharedArray` is . And it doesn't know that as it is not globally available identier. You need to import it from `k6/data`.

Comment: https://k6.io/docs/javascript-api/k6-data/sharedarray/